# scipy.opimize.minimize fails with constraints for ordered solution vector

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I am trying to solve a linear equations with minimize (algorithm=SLSQP), having a set of constraints: The sum of the solution vector components has to be 1 (or at least very close to it, to minimize the error) and second constraint enforces the vector components to be ordered, with x_0 being largest and x_n having the smallest magnitude. Further I set bounds, as each vector component has

This is my code so far:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import rand
from scipy.optimize import lsq_linear

#Linear equation Ax = b


def fmin(x,A,b):
    y = np.dot(A, x) - b
    return np.dot(y, y)


#Test data
b = np.array([172,8,7.4,24,21,0.8,0.1]) 

A_t = np.array(
    [[188,18.4,16.5,3.4,2.1,1.77,0.075],
     [405,0,0,99.8,99.8,0,0.0054],
     [90.5,0.4,0.009,19.7,15.6,1.06,0.012],
     [322,0,0,79,79,0.3,0.3],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [362,0.25,0.009,89.2,0,0.43,0.019],
     [37,1.4,0.2,7.3,1,4.5,0.1],
     [26,0.29,0.038,6.1,2.4,0.4,0.053]])
A = A_t.T
#=========================


m = np.shape(A)[0]
n = np.shape(A)[1]


x0 = np.full(n, 0.5) 

args = (A,b)
bnds = (( (1*10e-100, 1), )*n) #all x_i must be between 0 and 1
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 1.0-np.sum(x) }] #sum(x_i) = 1

#consider order of vectors as constraints
for i in range(n-1):
    cons = cons + [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x : x[i] - x[i+1] }]

res = minimize(fmin, x0, args, method='SLSQP',
bounds=bnds,constraints=cons,tol=1e-2,options={'disp': False})

print ("\n res\n", res)
print("Sum of coefficients {}".format(np.sum(res.x)))
print("Difference vector:\n{}".format(np.dot(A,res.x) - b))
```

Unfortunately the algorithm false with

```
 res
      fun: 317820.09898084006
     jac: array([205597.34765625, 481389.625     , 105853.7265625 , 382592.76953125,
            0.        , 416196.953125  ,  42268.78125   ,  30196.81640625])
 message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
    nfev: 10
     nit: 5
    njev: 1
  status: 8
 success: False
       x: array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
Sum of coefficients 4.0
Difference vector:
[5.4325e+02 2.3700e+00 9.7800e-01 1.2825e+02 7.8950e+01 3.4300e+00
 1.8220e-01]
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to sort this out. In fact for the test data in this example I know that the right solution should be 0.58 for x_0 and 0.12 for x_2.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a complete reproducible example. What is your objective `fmin`? Note also that `minimize` solves nonlinear problems, i.e. at least the objective or one of the constraints is not linear. In case your objective function is linear, you face a linear problem (LP) that can be solved with [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html).

Comment: Hi, sorry I just added the missing `fmin` above and updated the initial post. You are right that it is a linear problem. I probably need some time to figure out how to translate the above set constraints for the new solver, if no easier adaption is proposed in the meantime. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the discussion in the comments: Your objective function is nonlinear in the optimization variable `x`. Thus, this is a nonlinear optimization problem. The reason for the error message is quite simple: Your initial guess `x0` lies outside the feasible region. You can easily verify that it doesn't fulfill your first constraint `1.0 - np.sum(x) = 0`.

However, note also that you need to capture the loop variable `i` when creating your lambda constraint expressions in a loop. Otherwise, you add the constraint `lambda x: x[n-2] - x[n-1]` seven times. See, e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id10) for more details.

Creating the constraints correctly by

```py
for i in range(n-1):
    cons = cons + [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, i=i: x[i] - x[i+1] }]
```

and providing the feasible initial guess `x0 = np.ones(n)/n` yields

```
     fun: 114.90196737679031
     jac: array([3550.86690235, 7911.74978828, 1787.36224174, 6290.006423  ,
          0.        , 7580.9283762 ,  757.60069752,  528.41590595])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 66
     nit: 6
    njev: 6
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.38655391, 0.08763516, 0.08763516, 0.08763516, 0.08763516,
       0.08763515, 0.08763516, 0.08763516])
```

However, for larger problem's it's highly recommended to rewrite your second constraint:

```py
D = np.eye(n) - np.eye(n, k=1)
D[-1, -1] = 0.0

cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 1.0-np.sum(x) }]
cons += [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: D @ x}]
```

Now the solver only needs to evaluate 2 constraints instead of `n+1` constraints in each iteration. You can further speed up the solver by providing gradients and jacobians, [see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67932445/least-squares-optimization-in-python-with-single-equal-constraint/67933475#67933475).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards that obvious error. It makes a lot of sense and the constraint the way you put the constraint in a vector form is very elegant.

I am surprised though that I got a rather different solution and was wondering whether you used the test data that I provided above?

For some reason I get 
```x: array([0.38656138, 0.08763409, 0.08763409, 0.08763409, 0.08763409, 0.08763409, 0.08763409, 0.08763409])``` as a solution.

Comment: @s1m0n The second solution is the right one. I overlooked an error in the initial post for creating the constraints. I edited my answer.

Comment: Just had time to have a deeper look with further test data. Unfortunately, it seems that the algorithm always spits out a solution vector composed as: ```x: array([x0, x1, x1, x1, x1, x1, x1, x1])```. That means that the first vector component is some value and all other components are smaller than the first, but have the same value. After all the solutions I get are not what the ground truth solutions suggest. For the above test data I would expect 0.58 for x0 and 0.12 for x2. I wonder if still something is missing or if the output I get is expected for the given problem & constraints.

Comment: Sorry, but I very much appreciate your input so far and thank you for your dedication! Unfortunately, I am not eligible to upvote anything (I can only do that with 15 reputation) and as it is not clear yet whether your post above is the right answer, I refrained from accepting it. However, I ticked it again until a better answer comes up, but am not sure whether that is the right thing to do, as for me this problem is not fully solved.

Comment: @s1m0n Your problem is a convex optimization problem. Therefore, each found local minimizer is a global minimizer, i.e. there's no better solution. However, the global minimizer is not unique. So it's possible that there are other global minimizers (like the solution you'd expect) with the same objective function value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for another response. I will try to find other ways to improve the algorithm that this optimizer is embedded in. Also will upvote your answer as soon as I got 15 reputation. Thanks and keep up the great work!